# Calculate sum of increase in value with python

Tags: python

I would like to count the total of a increasing numbers They look like this: 
3
4
5
7
9
11
4
5
8
10
5
8
9

So i need the sum of the increase in value, for this example that would be: (11-3)+(10-4)+(9-5)= 8+6+4=18.

Is there a simple way to do this with code?

Comment: Where are the values coming from and in what data structure? have you tried anything from your side. Please add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
i = res = 0 
while i < len(arr): 
    low = high = arr[i] 
    while i != len(arr) and arr[i] >= high: 
        high = arr[i] 
        i += 1 
    res += high - low   
print(res)
```

> 18

Answer (score 0):

```
def groupSequence(lst): 
  " Creates sublists of ascending elements "
    res = [[lst[0]]] 

    for i in range(1, len(lst)): 
        if lst[i] > lst[i-1]: # test that next element is greater
            res[-1].append(lst[i]) 

        else: 
            res.append([lst[i]]) 
    return res 

a = [3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 4, 5, 8, 10, 5, 8, 9]
res = sum((max(x)-min(x) for x in groupSequence(a)))
print(res) #18
```

Comment: Thank you the answers i wil try them out.